# Output to printer Powershell

Tags: powershell

When running my script, I would like to have the results go to my printer. I can get the content of the page to print but I am having issues printing the verbose output of a command.

Working:

```
Get-Content c:\my-file.txt | Out-Printer
```

Not Working:

```
Copy-Item C:\Account\* C:\Account-2\ -verbose
```

Output says:

> "VERBOSE: performing operation Copy File on Target "Item: C:\Account* C:\Account-2\"

How can I get what the Output says to print on my printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the Verbose stream (4) to the Output Stream (1) prior to redirecting the Output stream to the printer with the `Out-Printer` cmdlet.

```
Copy-Item C:\Account* C:\Account-2\ -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-Printer
```

Comment: Copy-Item C:\Account\* C:\Account-2\ -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-Printer
Copy-Item C:\Account3\* C:\Account-3\ -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-Printer
When trying to implement the above i get Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
At \\emc-cifs1\users\cneal\Desktop\mypsScript.ps1:7 char:29
+ Ampersand not allowed. The &   operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? If I remember right, I think you will need 4.0+ for the `&` operator.  So if it's 3.0 you could redirect to a file then `Get-Content | Out-Printer` the file.

Comment: It's version 2.

Comment: There may be an arcane way of doing this in 2, but I don't know of it. If you want stream redirection in this form, you will probably need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, really appreciate it!!